# "Metrics" definition and usage

Tags: terminology, word-usage, british-english

Does the term "metric" (or plural "metrics") apply only to the metric system, or can it be used to define something that does not apply the metric system?

Comment: *Metric*, as a noun, simply means *measurement*. The term *metric system* was coined after this sense of the word, not the other way around. To call something a metric in no way invokes the metric system. If I say "he weighs 150 pounds", that's a metric, but has nothing to do with the metric system.

Comment: @Dan Bron. That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JJMDriessen Nuh uh. Answers have to be supported. Comments don't ;)

Comment: @JJMDriessen - Ah, but if one made it an answer someone would insist on it being documented with references, and that's tiresome to do.

Comment: @DanBron, I'll support your answer! :-)

Comment: @series0ne - Would you use scaffolding of some sort, a truss, suspension cables??

Comment: @HotLicks whilst I admire your wit, I think an upvote and accept will suffice

Comment: @series0ne You have my unqualified permission to post my comment (or simply a paraphrase) as a self-answer. No need to credit me.

Comment: Careful -- Gripe too much and we'll ask why you didn't just look is up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

With credit to Dan Bron, and I quote:

"*Metric*, as a noun, simply means measurement. The term *metric system* was coined after this sense of the word, not the other way around. To call something a metric in no way invokes the metric system. If I say "he weighs 150 pounds", that's a metric, but has nothing to do with the metric system."